# Flurry - Cannot read property 'initBuilder' of undefined

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I am getting error while initating **Flurry** in react native!

react native version:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.59.10

watchman version:  4.9.0

[image: flurry code in index.js]

[image: error while run app]

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by these step on iOS:
1- I installed latest version of SDK by npm install react-native-flurry-sdk --save
2- I used Pod file like this one bellow :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testproj' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testproj

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # Needed for debugging
    'RCTAnimation', # Needed for FlatList and animations running on native UI thread
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'react-native-flurry-sdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-flurry-sdk/ios'

end
```

and in my case I used pod update, but if it's your first time that are using pod you need to use pod install

and that's it. 
remeber when you are using pod you dont need to use react-native link, it makes problem.